# Get visual documentation from camel routes in Java?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, hawtio

I'm new to apache camel and made some routes working properly via Java DSL.

Now I'm wondering if there is a chance to get automatic a visual representation of these routes with JBoss Fuse?

I mean not by drawing it by hand again, more for automatic documention :-)

Edit: 
*Since a downvote seems to be easier than a answer I try to rephrase my question a bit.*
I'm looking for a possibility to reverse engineer my defined routes (Java) and get a picture with boxes out of it.

Hawtoi, what I tried before, gives a beautiful result but also a lot of other stuff I don't need for my documentation.
Therefore I took a look at JBoss Fuse. But here I can only draw my processes and save them as a blueprint.xml. 
Is the way from Java code to blueprint.xml not possible in JBoss Fuse? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JBoss Camel Developer Tools for Eclipse can visualize Camel routes loaded from XML files. You can then save those diagrams etc for documentation purposes.

It does not yet work with Java routes, but they have talked about adding support for that in the future. Mind Java is harder as its Java code and end users can do a lot of *other* stuff than just regular Camel routing so parsing that to visual diagram is harder than XML.

https://tools.jboss.org/features/apachecamel.html

But at this moment of writing there is no tool to visualize Camel routes from Java DSL.

The Apache Camel IDEA plugin has a ticket to see if we can add route visualization for XML and Java in the future: https://github.com/camel-idea-plugin/camel-idea-plugin/issues/27

Comment: Added about Camel IDEA plugin in the answer

Comment: What about the camel-maven-plugin? https://camel.apache.org/camel-maven-plugin.html

Comment: the link is down