# visualize Camel routes from Java DSL

Tags: java, apache-camel

Is there a way to visualize Camel routes from Java DSL? If so what is the best way to do this? If not are there any work arounds to visualize Camel routes from Java DSL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get visual documentation from camel routes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596563/get-visual-documentation-from-camel-routes-in-java)

Comment: I'm not really sure how you want the routes and the EIPs to be visualized. In one of my tech-demo applications I used AWS XRay (distributed tracing) to ["visualize" the invoked beans and processors for a processed message](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security). The same should be achiveable via OpenTracing and Zipkin (or the like)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! You can use `hawt.io` to visualise the camel routes.

It's very easy to use. Just plug it in to a running application with a valid Camel context, and you can visualise your routes.

https://hawt.io/

Answer (score 4):

I have created a simple open-source project to visualize Apache Camel routes written in Java DSL.

[image: camel-net]

You can find the code and instructions how to set it up on GitHub:
https://github.com/BenjaminBrandmeier/camel-net